# Best solution to deploy (copy) the last version to the server using Jenkins Pipline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Here is my Jenkins Pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node:6-alpine' 
            args '-p 3000:3000' 
        }
    }
    environment { 
        CI = 'true'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
                sh 'npm build'
            }
        }
        stage('Deliver') { 
            steps {
                sh './jenkins/scripts/deliver.sh' 
                input message: 'Finished using the web site? (Click "Proceed" to continue)' 
                sh './jenkins/scripts/kill.sh'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') { 
            steps {
                sh './jenkins/scripts/deploy.sh'
            }
        }
    } }
```

I use Docker and `jenkinsci/blueocean` image to run Jenkins. The first two stages are kind of standard to build a NodeJS app, the third one, however, is the part that I want to Jenkins copy new files to the server. Here is the `deploy.sh` files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -x
scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r dist/* deviceappstore:/var/www/my_website/static/
```

There are two problems, first `jenkinsci/blueocean` does not have `scp` (not setup) and second, the `~/.ssh/config` does not exist inside of the Jankins docker image then SCP will fail to authenticate. My solution was to build a custom image extends from `jenkinsci/blueocean`, setup SCP and copy config file and SSH key into it.

There are some plugins like [Publish Over SSH](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) but it seems it's not useful for Pipeline projects.

Is there any better solution? It the whole scenario right or I'm doing something wrong? I'm looking for most secure and standard solution for this problem.

Comment: What's the problem with your solution (copy `~/.ssh/config` etc.)? Did it work and you are looking for some better solution or did it fail? If it failed, what was the error?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found a good solution.
Thanks to [SSH Agent plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin) I can easily pass the credentials to the SCP command and copy the files to the server. Something like this:

```
...

stage('Deploy') { 
    steps {
        sshagent(['my SSH']) {
            echo 'this works...'
            sh 'scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r dist/* my_server:/var/www/my_site/static/'
        }
    }
}

...
```

This is perfect because all the credentials are inside of Jenkins server and there's nothing about it in the repo.

And to be able to use this, there's just one solution. You need to use `apk` inside of the `jenkinsci/blueocean` (alpine) image and setup openssh:

```
apk add openssh
```

Or better solution create a new `Dockerfile` and build your own version.